# No agent found in pool which satisfies the specified demands: npm, Agent.Version

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I've created a Azure agent on my PC and I'm trying to run my build pipeline on it:

```
pool:
  name: TestPool
  vmImage: PeterPCAgent
```

When I run it:

> ##[error]No agent found in pool TestPool which satisfies the specified demands: npm, Agent.Version -gtVersion 2.163.1

On my PC I have installed npm:

```
C:\Users\alucardu>npm -v
6.14.6
```

I've restarted the server and pc but I keep getting the same message.

In the Azure TestPool dashboard it doesn't show any agent either:

[image]

I did run through the `New agent` steps though.

Also when I close the local agent and run the pipeline I get the same message. So it looks like the issue is not NPM but that Azure is not connecting to my local agent:

[image]

Comment: Check all the pools and see where the agent is connected.

Comment: Figured it out :) Didn't config the agent to the right pool. During config I added the agent to the default pool. So I removed the agent config from my local machine. Run the config again and now in pool added it to `TestPool` and voila :)

Comment: Great :) I glad I helped you to find the RCA, I also added it as an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see from the screenshot that you don't have agents in `TestPool` and this is the reason for the error message.

Check in which pool the agent is installed and change the pool name, or install a new agent in `TestPool`.